# What is the maximum capacity for a Time Capsule's hard drive?

Tags: upgrade, time-capsule

I am thinking of buying a Time Capsule with a small hard drive and upgrading the drive to something larger. There is [ample documentation](http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Replacing+Apple+Time+Capsule+HDD/2750/1?revisionid=HEAD) on the web as to how to do it, but I am having a hard time finding any details as to what the upper limits of drive size are. It's especially confusing since there are [four generations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Capsule_%28Apple%29#Product_numbers) of Time Capsule, and each one may have a different upper limit. So, what is the upper limit of each? And, if you only know the answer to one specific one, that would be great, too.

Comment: It will be interesting to hear what size drives people have placed internally once they don't care about warranty coverage. Most I know that want more than 3 TB of Time Machine storage get a [Synology NAS](http://www.synology.com/) unless they just want more space and are OK connecting several 3 TB drives (or larger) to the USB port via a hub.

Answer (score 7):

Nobody seems to know what the official drive size limits are, but I just connected an 18TB hardware RAID to a 1st generation Time Capsule, and it works. To duplicate my setup:

Configure a 4-drive hardware RAID using this enclosure:

https://www.newegg.com/sans-digital-tr4utbpn/p/N82E16816111149

(I used four 6TB drives and set it up as a RAID 5)

Connect the RAID enclosure to the SATA connector on the Time Capsule's logic board using this cable:

https://www.newegg.com/p/N82E16812119251?Item=N82E16812119251

This Time Capsule has pretty much been gutted over the years, so the only thing left is the logic board itself. It's powered by a 2A 5VDC external brick, WiFi and routing are disabled. It's just a hack NAS at this point...but it handles an 18TB drive.

Comment: FWIW, when formatting that RAID prior to initial connection to the Time Capsule, you need to make it a single non-journaled HFS+ volume. To do this, use "diskutil eraseDisk HFS+ RAID_Volume /dev/diskX" where X is the device number for the drive, found in Disk Utility. The TC will repartition the drive into journaled HFS+ volumes, but for some reason it has to start out as a single non-journaled HFS+ volume.

Answer (score 3):

I’m running a 4th gen. A1409 Time Capsule, originally equipped with a 2 TB drive.  I replaced that with a 4 TB WD Green (iirc) with no problems so far.

Answer (score -1):

Time Capsule 802.11n (1st generation) introduced Jan 2008 is working with 2TB drive. I did not try larger (yet).